# How to calculate the Full Width at Half-Power (FWHP) at the output of two SMF and DCF connected in cascade

Tags: fiber-optics

Assuming a Gaussian pulse with a wavelength $\lambda$ and $FWHP_i$ , a SMF with dispersion $D_{SMF}$ and length $L_{SMF}$, a DCF with dispersion $D_{DCF}$ and length $L_{DCF}$

How can I calculate the FWHP at the output of the fiber if they are supposed to be connected in cascade?

Comment: SMF is Single-Mode Fiber and DCF is Dispersion Compensation Fiber

Comment: The RP Photonics Encyclopedia tutorial on [Passive Fiber Optics](https://www.rp-photonics.com/passive_fiber_optics.html) might help.